# What is the relevant "Core Networking" item in Windows Defender Firewall for DNS over TCP?

Tags: dns, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-defender

In Window 10, the Windows Defender Firewall, the relevant item for standard DNS over UDP is "Core Networking - DNS (UPD-out)"  You can enable/disable specific IP addresses in this rule.

Some DNS requests go out through TCP. What is the relevant rule?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the rule in Outbound Rules you mentioned, there are 2 rules in Inbound Rules of Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security related to DNS services including UDP and TCP. They are **DNS (TCP, Incoming)** and **DNS (UDP, Incoming)**.

Attaching the screenshot for your reference.

[image]